# How to solve node_modules when I push nodejs project to server use jenkins?

Tags: node.js, jenkins

I use the Publish over ftp plugins to push the code to server.The build time is too long because the node_modules.

Should I make a war or use `npm install` after ftp?

Comment: A full guide to CICD Nodejs Application here : https://blog.risingstack.com/continuous-deployment-of-node-js-applications/

Answer (score 0):

if possible, I suggest you to use git, add one file named as `.gitignore` file and add below line in it.

> node_modules/*

and save it

Comment: I am using git ,and I have the file to ignore node_modules .but  how can I use the npm package on the server if not have node_modules

Comment: after uploading your files on server use

`npm install` to load the node modules